# Books on higher-order logic

Tags: reference-request, logic

Could somebody recommend me some books on higher-order logic?

I can't find any on the subject by searching on Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe authors avoid putting the words "higher-order logic" in their titles to avoid frightening potential readers $\ddot{\smile}$. I'd recommend Peter Andrews' [An Introduction to Mathematical Logic and Type Theory: To Truth Through Proof](http://gtps.math.cmu.edu/tttp.html)

Answer (score 5):

See :

- Stewart Shapiro, [Foundations without Foundationalism : A Case for Second-Order Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=xm5eWgjpYU0C&printsec=frontcover) (1991).